# jump multiple tags referring a sibling tag in XML JAVA DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

Below is my XML. I just want to fetch the GLOBAL_EMP_NO value for those who has EMPLOYEE_STATUS = 0.

XML:

```
<GLOBAL_EMP_NO>A12345678</GLOBAL_EMP_NO>
<EMP_NO>12345678</EMP_NO>
<FIRST_NAME>Tushar Furlenco</FIRST_NAME>
<PREF_FIRST_NAME/>
<MIDDLE_NAME/>
<LAST_NAME>Joseph</LAST_NAME>
<PREF_LAST_NAME>Tushar</PREF_LAST_NAME>
<SUFFIX/>
<SMTP_EMAIL>TUSHAR.FURLENCO@EMAIL.COM</SMTP_EMAIL>
<EMPLOYEE_STATUS>0</EMPLOYEE_STATUS>
```

I tried the below syntax which is working fine and fetches the GLOBAL_EMP_NO when EMPLOYEE_STATUS = 0. But I am not sure if this is a right practice. Can anyone advise on this please?

Thanks

JAVA Code:

```
Element element = (Element) node;
ArrayList emp0 = new ArrayList();
String emp_status = element.getElementsByTagName("EMPLOYEE_STATUS").item(0).getTextContent();
if (emp_status.equals("0")) {
emp0.add(element.getElementsByTagName("EMPLOYEE_STATUS").item(0).getPreviousSibling().getPreviousSibling().
                    getPreviousSibling().getPreviousSibling().getPreviousSibling().getPreviousSibling().getPreviousSibling()
                    .getPreviousSibling().getPreviousSibling().getPreviousSibling().getTextContent());
}
```

Comment: Why can't you get the value of GLOBAL_EMP_NO using the same way as EMPLOYEE_STATUS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

```
String xml = "<Root>" +
               "<Item>" +
                 "<No>A123</No>" +
                 "<Other>Foo</Other>" +
                 "<Status>0</Status>" +
               "</Item>" +
               "<Item>" +
                 "<No>B456</No>" +
                 "<Other>Bar</Other>" +
                 "<Status>1</Status>" +
               "</Item>" +
               "<Item>" +
                 "<No>C789</No>" +
                 "<Other>Baz</Other>" +
                 "<Status>0</Status>" +
               "</Item>" +
             "</Root>";
Element root = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
               .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml))).getDocumentElement();
NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("Item");
for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
    Element item = (Element) items.item(i);
    if ("0".equals(item.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0).getTextContent()))
        System.out.println(item.getElementsByTagName("No").item(0).getTextContent());
}
```

*Output*

```
A123
C789
```

Comment: Yesssss!!!. Thanks a lot Andreas. I could have thought about it though..